# Can a government commit a crime?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, constitutional-law, federalism, governmental-liability

Can a state government be convicted for a federal crime, or can the federal government be convicted for a state crime? The latter situation could happen despite the supremacy of federal law over state law if the federal government did something under an unconstitutional federal law in violation of a constitutional state law.

Answer (score 3):

> Can a state government be convicted for a federal crime, or can the
> federal government be convicted for a state crime?

No.

Government officials can be guilty of crimes. Private corporations can be guilty of crimes. Governments, themselves, cannot be guilty of crimes.

Governments can sometimes be subject to civil liability, but this is very different from being guilty of a crime.

The exact reason that this is the case is a bit trickier to articulate, since it is such a foundational concept that it is never actually tested in litigation.

It is worth noting that the under Article III of the U.S. Constitution, the only court in the United States with jurisdiction over disputes between the U.S. federal government and U.S. states, without their consent, is the U.S. Supreme Court in its original jurisdiction, which has never entertained a criminal case of this kind.

First and foremost, this is a question of sovereign immunity from criminal prosecution, which has not been waived.

Second, it flows from the principle that a sovereign government can only be made a party to litigation in its own courts (except in the U.S. Supreme Court), although this only applies to state governments and the federal government, not to local governments, and from the supremacy clause. Together, these principles deny state courts jurisdiction over the federal government without its consent.

Third, it flows from how a "person" who can be prosecuted criminally is defined. This definition exists, in part, because a criminal prosecution of the federal government or a state government, which could only result in a penalty amounting to a fine payable from that government's general revenues, would basically be punishing the alleged victims of any crime it allegedly committed in their own name ("the People").